# When we do uniform cost search, do we need to know where the destination or goal state is?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, brute-force, uniform-cost-search

Since uniform cost search is belong to uninform/ blind search algorithm we have no heuristic details. But when we do uniform cost search we have to reach the goal state within the lowest cost path. For that we need to know where the goal node is? this is a contradiction. Someone please explain this.

I have search from defferent sources about this. But i can't found any reasonable answer for this.

Comment: Please attempt a code solution, and form a question based on it, or post on a site more suited to this question: https://cs.stackexchange.com/, https://ai.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

When we apply the uniform cost search technique, we just know what is the best possibility for the next node and then we keep on doing this until we reach the goal state. Basically, we look for the least cost or best solution for each node at a time, and then overall cost is added.
We do not know anything about the goal node until we are at the node just before it.

Comment: But then sometimes we can't find the goal node when we reaching only least cost node?

Comment: @B.AThisaradilshan Yes, it is possible that with a least-cost search, you do not find the goal state - that is sometimes called "finding a local minimum".

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).